# Facebook "Like Button" does not appear on PHP pages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

Hello Stackoverflow Community!

Has anyone else ever had a problem with the Facebook "Like button" not appearing on PHP pages? I am stumped on this one. This is the code I am using (taken directly from the Facebook Developers page):

This code comes right after the opening body tag (as suggested by Facebook)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And this code generates the button (I replaced the actual client's page name with "PageToLike")

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/PageToLike" data-width="300" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

The button renders on HTML pages but not on PHP pages! The code for the button is contained in the site's template, and the site has two PHP pages that have very little PHP scripts inside the template's editable regions, so I didn't modify the button code on those pages, as it is non-editable.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? If so, any suggestions on how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Any error messages in browser console? Live example?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't matter whether it is a PHP page or an HTML page (or ASPX or any other equivalent), as what the browser receives is just HTML.

Check the final HTML source that is received by the browser as you may have some difference that you weren't aware you had.   I'd assume that the two will have differences, so try to reconcile these differences one at a time until you find the one that is causing the Like button to stop working.

Without seeing source it's hard to guess, but I'd been looking at things like docType declaration, any additional scripts on the page, HTML validity.